# complex sql query comparing data and creating a list

Tags: mysql, sql

I've users table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` char(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` char(12) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

books table:

```
CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `book` char(55) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `book` (`book`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `books_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And read table:

```
CREATE TABLE `read` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `book_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `No duplicates` (`user_id`,`book_id`),
  KEY `book_id` (`book_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `connections_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `connections_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`book_id`) REFERENCES `books` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I'd like for user_id = 1, to create list of other user_id's - matching point is the common books they have read. So if user_id = 1 and user_id = 2 have in common 5 books then user_id should be on that list. I'm not so good at sql, so any recommendation on how to achieve this, even little optimisation tip will be much appreciated.

Comment: Would this be a list of all user_id's or display other books read by others with for instance a parameter variable?

Comment: List of user_ids that have matching set of books read. And I want to control this matching variable, like match 10 books etc.

Comment: You should in your books table remove the userid colum as that will be linked in the read table.

Comment: Ive gotta leave im going to the movies. If you question is still unanswered when im back i will try to help you out!

Comment: @KayNelson thanks! :) enjoy the movie.

Comment: Did you try suggested solution?

Comment: @KayNelson yep it worked like charm, thanks for looking in :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution - gives users that read 5 or more common books

```
SELECT r2.user_id
FROM `read` r1
JOIN `read` r2
ON r1.user_id <> r2.user_id AND r1.book_id = r2.book_id
WHERE r1.user_id = 1
GROUP BY r2.user_id
HAVING count(*) >= 5
```

If users must have exactly 5 common books (no less and no more), a clause with `HAVING` must be changed into:

```
 HAVING count(*) = 5
```

Demo: --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a9b7/1

A simple change to the query gives pairs of users that read >= 5 common books:

```
SELECT r1.user_id user1, r2.user_id user2
FROM `read` r1
JOIN `read` r2
ON r1.user_id < r2.user_id AND r1.book_id = r2.book_id
-- WHERE r1.user_id = 1
GROUP BY r1.user_id, r2.user_id
HAVING count(*) >= 5;
```

Demo: --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a9b7/3

---- EDIT ---- 
To order users by number of matches use this query:

```
SELECT r1.user_id user1, r2.user_id user2, 
       count(*) number_of_matches
FROM `read` r1
JOIN `read` r2
ON r1.user_id < r2.user_id AND r1.book_id = r2.book_id
-- WHERE r1.user_id = 1
GROUP BY r1.user_id, r2.user_id
HAVING count(*) >= 5
ORDER BY number_of_matches DESC
-- you may also use:
-- ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
;
```

demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a9b7/8

Comment: Hey, this works perfectly, thanks! How would I order this list by number of matches? In case if I've >=5 what if user_id = 10 has 25 matches and user_id = 11 5, can I've an order?

Comment: I appended an example how to order results by number of matches